# Is this use of select_related() beneficial?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), there is the following example.

```
>>> b = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)

# Update all the headlines belonging to this Blog.
>>> Entry.objects.select_related().filter(blog=b).update(headline='Everything is the same')
```

And the example is based on the following definitions of models.

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

What is the benefit of having `select_related()` in the line of `Entry.objects.select_related().filter(blog=b).update(headline='Everything is the same')`
?

I don't see any benefit of having `select_related()` in the update statement. In fact, I think `Entry.objects.filter(blog=b).update(headline='Everything is the same')` has a better performance for it doesn't perform an unneeded inner join and doesn't populate the unneeded Blog objects.

What do you think?

Comment: No. `.select_related` has *nothing* to do with `.filter(..)`ing. It only means that when you *retrieve* data, it will already retrieve related objects, but filtering, annotating, etc. will all join with the necessary tables when used.

Comment: I created a Django ticket for this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32187#ticket

Comment: Update: they fixed the documentation: https://github.com/django/django/commit/c448e614c60cc97c6194c62052363f4f501e0953 likely will be in the next release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any benefit of having `select_related()` in the update statement.

**Indeed**. [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) has *nothing* to do with [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter). It only means that when you *retrieve* data, it will already retrieve related objects, and wrap these columns in objects that are accessed through the `ForeignKey`. It thus is a mechanism to avoid *N+1 problems*.

But for *filtering*, *annotating*, etc. Django will construct a query that makes a join with the necessary tables when used. Here one thus can omit the `.select_related(…)`. This will normally be ignored by the Django ORM, since an `UPDATE` on a query with `JOIN`s will normally raise exceptions at the database level, since then it is no longer clear *how* to update this.

Likely this is a copy-paste from the [*One-to-many relationships* sections of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships), where we see:

> ```
> >>> e = Entry.objects.select_related().get(id=2)
> ```

**Update**: I created a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32187#ticket) for this, and it was fixed in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c448e614c60cc97c6194c62052363f4f501e0953)